# Whay not jQuery .sortable is not a function?

Tags: jquery, laravel

When I am Create Drag and Droppable Datatables Using jQuery UI Sortable in Laravel Then Drag and drop not working in this code ...

Create Drag and Droppable Datatables Using jQuery UI Sortable in Laravel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Create Drag and Droppable Datatables Using jQuery UI Sortable in Laravel</title>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                <h3 class="text-center mb-4">Drag and Drop Datatables Using jQuery UI Sortable - Demo </h3>
                <table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="30px">#</th>
                      <th>Title</th>
                      <th>Created At</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="tablecontents">
                    @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <tr class="row1" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">
                          <td class="pl-3"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></td>
                          <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                          <td>{{ date('d-m-Y h:m:s',strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>                  
                </table>
                <hr>
                <h5>Drag and Drop the table rows and <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="window.location.reload()">REFRESH</button> the page to check the Demo.</h5> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
            $("#table").DataTable();
    
            $( "#tablecontents" ).sortable({
              items: "tr",
              cursor: 'move',
              opacity: 0.6,
              update: function() {
                  sendOrderToServer();
              }
            });
    
            function sendOrderToServer() {
              var order = [];
              var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
              $('tr.row1').each(function(index,element) {
                order.push({
                  id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
                  position: index+1
                });
              });
    
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                dataType: "json", 
                url: "{{ url('post-sortable') }}",
                    data: {
                  order: order,
                  _token: token
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == "success") {
                      console.log(response);
                    } else {
                      console.log(response);
                    }
                }
              });
            }
          });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I can't understand what I did wrong with this code. Can you tell me the mistake by analyzing this code? Thanks.

Comment: You don't load jquery UI

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery ui also:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```